# Crosscheck arrays and delete from DB what is left over

Tags: arrays, ruby, activerecord, ruby-1.8.7

I have two arrays, one with information from the old DB and one with information from the new DB.  I want to check what is in the old DB that is NOT in the new DB, and delete that.

I have done array1 - array2 and put the results in an array, but am not sure how to then remove them from the DB.  Any enum I have tried to call on it seems to break/not like being used with a fixnum.

Using ruby 1.8.7 running on an oracle DB, in case there is an easier way to do it inside oracle (first time using oracle so I am unfamiliar).

Comment: v1.8.7 is 7 years old this month! Time for an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use AR ORM, you could do:

```
(array1 - array2).each(&:destroy)
```

of you could simply [delete_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class):

```
(array1 - array2).delete_all
```

### EDIT based on comment:

Since `array1` and `array2` are arrays of `id`s, you could simply pass resulting array into `Merchant.where` clause and delete the collection all together:

```
ids_for_delete = (array1 - array2)
Merchant.find(ids_for_delete).delete_all
```

**Sidenote**: maintenance of Ruby versions 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 ended on July 31, 2014 - consider update.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned, as I keep getting 'undefined method `destroy' for Fixnum', that I am trying to delete integers (ex. array1 = Merchant.find(:all).map{|m| m.id} to get the ids).

Comment: I got it working with Merchant.find(ids_for_delete).delete_all
I'm not sure 1.8.7 has where...?  It wasn't liking it for me, at least.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Noahhh I can update the answer with the working code (I'm not familiar with Ruby 1.8.7) and you could accept it if it helped

Comment: Done, thank you!  I am unfamiliar with 1.8.7 as well, which is why I wasn't sure what I was missing.